# Spring Boot does not mapp GraphQL endpoints correctly

Tags: java, spring, maven, graphql, endpoint

## Introduction

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time now. I have searched for awnsers and tried many solutions, which failed. I am using Spring Boot version 3.0.0, and spring-boot-starter-graphql version 3.0.0. I will provide (what i belive to be) all the relevant information to solve this problem.

## Files

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>gorgeousSandwich</groupId>
   <artifactId>promotion</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>Promotion Microservice</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>17</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
         <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- OPEN API 3 (Swagger) -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
         <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
         <version>1.6.12</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>
                     <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                     <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                  </exclude>
               </excludes>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

### PromotionController.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class PromotionController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PromotionController.class);
    private final IPromotionService service;
    private final IPromotionMapper mapper;


    @MutationMapping
    public GraphQLPromotionDTO createPromotion(@Argument PromotionInput promotion) {
        try {
            PromotionDTO promotionDTO = promotion.toDTO();
            LOGGER.trace(String.format("Requesting the creation of a new promotion (%s)", promotionDTO));
            promotionDTO = service.createPromotion(promotionDTO);
            LOGGER.info("Order successfully created");
            return mapper.toGraphQLDTO(promotionDTO);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not create Shop!", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public List<GraphQLPromotionDTO> listAllPromotions() {
        System.out.println("Hehehe");
        Iterable<PromotionDTO> itr = service.getAll();
        List<GraphQLPromotionDTO> l = new ArrayList<>();
        itr.forEach(dto -> l.add(mapper.toGraphQLDTO(dto)));
        LOGGER.info("Retrieving all promotions");
        return l;
    }

    @QueryMapping
    public String health() {
        return "All systems Online!";
    }


    record PromotionInput(Float percentage, String from, String to, String shopId, PromotionType promotionType) {


        PromotionDTO toDTO() throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return new PromotionDTO(null, percentage, format.parse(from), format.parse(to), Long.parseLong(shopId), promotionType);
        }

    }
}
```

### schema.graphqls

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutator
}


type Mutator{
    createPromotion (
        promotion: PromotionInput
    ) : GraphQLPromotionDTO
}
type Query{
    listAllPromotions : [GraphQLPromotionDTO],
    health: String
}


input PromotionInput{
    percentage: Float
    from: String
    to: String
    shopId: ID
    promotionType: PromotionType
}

enum PromotionType{
    GLOBAL,
    LOCAL
}

type GraphQLPromotionDTO {
    id: ID
    percentage : Float
    from : String
    to : String
    shopId : ID
    promotionType: PromotionType
}
```

### Promotion.java

```
package gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Domain;


import gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Shared.domain.patterns.IAggregateRoot;
import gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Shared.domain.patterns.IEntity;
import gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Shared.domain.patterns.IEntityId;
import gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Shared.domain.valueobjects.Percentage;
import gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Shared.domain.valueobjects.TimeOfEffect;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
public abstract class Promotion implements IAggregateRoot<PromotionId> {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PromotionId id;
    @Embedded
    private TimeOfEffect timeOfEffect;
    @Embedded
    private Percentage percentage;
    @Enumerated
    private PromotionType type;
    Promotion(TimeOfEffect timeOfEffect, Percentage percentage, PromotionType type) {
        this.id = new PromotionId();
        this.timeOfEffect = timeOfEffect;
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.type=type;
    }

    Promotion(PromotionId id, TimeOfEffect timeOfEffect, Percentage percentage, PromotionType type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.timeOfEffect = timeOfEffect;
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.type=type;
    }

    protected Promotion() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean sameAs(IEntity<? extends IEntityId> otherEntity) {
        if (otherEntity instanceof Promotion) {
            Promotion otherPromotion = ((Promotion) otherEntity);
            return obtainId().id().equals(otherPromotion.obtainId().id());
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public PromotionId obtainId() {
        return id;
    }

    public TimeOfEffect getTimeOfEffect() {
        return timeOfEffect;
    }

    public Percentage getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public PromotionType getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

### GraphQLPromotionDTO.java

```
package gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Domain;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class GraphQLPromotionDTO {
    public String id;
    public float percentage;
    public String from;
    public String to;
    public String shopId;
    public PromotionType promotionType;
}
```

### PromotionType.java

```
package gorgeousSandwich.promotion.Domain;

public enum PromotionType {
    LOCAL,
    GLOBAL;
}
```

Thaks for all the help

## What i have tried already

I have tried to:

- Match the types of the DTO in the schema to the code
- @SchemaMapping instead of @QueryMapping and/or @MutationMapping
- Debug any endpoint (but none worked)

## Edit

Ok, i have already made progress. I can perform queries but mutations are still not working.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same issue as myself, i found the solution by learning how to spell.

> Mutator

must change to

> Mutation

Result:

```
schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}


type Mutation{
    createPromotion (
        promotion: PromotionInput!
    ) : GraphQLPromotionDTO
}
type Query{
    listAllPromotions : [GraphQLPromotionDTO!]!,
    health: String!
}


input PromotionInput{
    percentage: Float!
    from: String!
    to: String!
    shopId: ID
    promotionType: PromotionType!
}

enum PromotionType{
    GLOBAL,
    LOCAL
}

type GraphQLPromotionDTO {
    id: ID!
    percentage : Float!
    from : String!
    to : String!
    shopId : ID
    promotionType: PromotionType!
}
```

PS: Added null verification to each type